# Using injective functions to prove randomness

Tags: functions, random

Suppose we have a random subset of $\mathbb N$. My intuitive notion of randomness represents the ability to encode arbitrary real number.

Assume that $A$ is a random subset according to the above notion.

> Does the existence of injective function from $A$ to set $S$ prove that $S$ is random? Is this notion or similar one is already known?

Comment: No-one would usually say $\mathbb{N}$ was random, although there is an obvious injection from $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{N}$…

Comment: No. - Actually, "no" to almost all sentences: random subsets of $\Bbb N$ are a non-trivial matter; randomness has nothing to do with encoding real numbers; an injective function $A\to S$ does not make $S$ random